# Android app to add latitude+longitude to an existing picture

Tags: android, photography, gps, exif

I want to add coordinates to a picture that has been taken without GPS activated.

Any app for this?

Requirements:

- Runs on Android
- Add coordinates to EXIF data
- Select point on a zoomable/scrollable map
- Free, ideally open source

Bonus:

- At startup, center map on my current location
- Batch addition
- Modification of existing coordinates, in case of GPS error

Answer (score 1):

Oh, there are [several of those](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=54#group_202). I have not tried any of them myself, but the probably best candidates seem to be:

- [PhotoMap Maker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/jp.suto.photomapmaker): meeting your criteria, but seems no longer maintained.
- [PhotoGeolocator](http://www.appbrain.com/app/edu.uoc.mperezma.main) seems to be worth a look as well.

**[EagleEye](http://www.appbrain.com/app/eu.bischofs.eagleeye)** is probably the best choice here. I use its companion app [PhotoMap](http://www.appbrain.com/app/eu.bischofs.photomap), and am quite happy with it (it's based on the very same code, but rather a "lite" version lacking e.g. the feature to show pics without GeoTags and add the latter). Support is superb, issues I had were usually fixed within a week (if not faster).

For your task, it shows you the picture along with a map, and lets you visually move the "pointer" to the coordinates you want to write to the photo's Exif data:

[image: EagleEye GeoTag]
<sup>Edit GeoTags with *EagleEye* (source: Google Play; click image for large variant)</sup>

Of course you can edit existing GeoTags the very same way: simply drag the baloon to where it belongs. The app has a ton of other useful features, including

- showing your photos by country or place
- include a "GPS path" to show the order they were taken (map view)
- show by year/month, distance, name, folder

And more. EagleEye is free and without any advertisements. Though I didn't use the app (yet) myself, most of its features (and behaviour) is known to me by its sister-app I'm using. Runs stable, is fun to work with. In short: This one you should definitely give a try :)